# Error Starting JBoss 5.1.0 Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: jboss5.x

I am trying to upgrade my application from JBoss 4 to 5 and my server throws errors when I try to start it. The error seems to tell me that there is a problem parsing a file but with the info in the log I can't identify which file. I placed some log snippets below.

org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Error creating managed object for vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-as/server/default/deploy/myApp.war/...

Caused by: org.jboss.xb.binding.JBossXBException: Failed to parse source: Connection timed out: connect
at org.jboss.xb.binding.parser.sax.SaxJBossXBParser.parse(SaxJBossXBParser.java:203)....

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please format your code before posting, it helps while reading. :)

Comment: I apologize I am having trouble formatting my post. I had more log info in there but it was a mess so I just out the most important info.